# Pattern for REST API with Image

Tags: image, api, rest, storage

I am in process of creating a REST API with image upload/retrieval capabiilty.

Instead of sending image data to server, for it to upload to the storage.
I am thinking of doing the following:

1. client directly uploads image to the storage (Azure Blob Storage)
2. obtain image url from the blob storage if upload is successful
3. send image metadata along with the image url in blob storage to Server to be maintained

Is this an acceptable approach in terms of managing image data (or videos or any non string data) through Rest API?

Also, what are some of pros/cons for setting up service this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from doing it that way, but it introduces a bit of unnecessary complexity:

1. The client needs to be aware of different endpoints to handle this particular type of request.
2. If something changes in your Azure Blob Storage endpoint, you have to change the client code. And if you have users using an old cached version of the app, they may get odd errors.
3. Your client has to be carefully implemented to handle the process of first uploading the image to Azure and then sending the URL to the API. If the user refreshes, clicks the upload button again, or if there's a network issue, you will face complicated scenarios.

My recommendation is that you can encapsulate this complexity in the server, where you have better control of what's going on, by letting the client send a POST request with `multipart/form-data` MIME type. The server can respond to this with details about the endpoint for the image in the server.

Comment: Thanks! I think this was what I looking for!